# Grab all HTML Source Code using VB6 WebBrowser Control

Tags: vb6

I've tried `Webbrowser1.Document.body.OuterHTML` and `Webbrowser1.Document.body.innerHTML`, but both are missing JS links and CSS stylings, any way to get the full html, seems it is just grabbing the html within the body not the full source.

Answer (score 1):

Found out...
WebBrowser1.Document.documentElement.outerHTML